# Wordpress // remove post type slug for URL

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, slug, custom-taxonomy

I have created a CPT and several custom taxonomies applied to this CPT.

At the moment my URL are as follow (using a plugin) :

www.example.com/[cpt]/[taxonomy-term]/post

For a specific cpt, I'd like to move to :

www.example.com/[taxonomy-term]/post

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna have custom slug without `[cpt]` for the custom post_type, you need to pass this value in args array

```
$args['rewrite'] = array(
     'slug'       => 'your-custom-post-type',
     'with_front' => false,
 ),
```

and after this update your permalinks